Comparison between pushforward-pullback and quasi-coherent pushforward-pullback
In the following, an algebraic stack means a stack over the big fppf site of a scheme, admitting a smooth, representable, surjective morphism from a scheme (no separation hypotheses), and let $\mathsf{D}(X)$ (resp. $\mathsf{D}_{\textrm{qc}}(X)$) denote the unbounded derived category of the abelian category of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules on the lisse-'etale topos of $X$ (resp. the full subcategory of $\mathsf{D}(X)$ consisting of objects whose cohomology sheaves are quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules).
For a representable morphism of algebraic stacks $f : X\to Y,$ there exists a functor
$$\mathbf{L}(f_{\textrm{qc}})^* : \mathsf{D}_{\textrm{qc}}(Y)\to\mathsf{D}_{\textrm{qc}}(X)$$
such that $\mathscr{H}^0(\mathbf{L}f_{\textrm{qc}}^*\mathcal{F}[0])\cong f^*\mathcal{F},$ for any $\mathcal{F}\in\mathsf{QCoh}(Y)$. Moreover, $\mathbf{L}f_{\textrm{qc}}^*$ admits a right adjoint
$$\mathbf{R}(f_{\textrm{qc}})_* : \mathsf{D}_{\textrm{qc}}(X)\to\mathsf{D}_{\textrm{qc}}(Y),$$
which does not in general agree with the ordinary derived pushforward $\mathbf{R}f_*.$ However, there is a comparison morphism
$$\mathbf{R}(f_{\textrm{qc}})_*\mathcal{F}\to\mathbf{R}f_*\mathcal{F}$$
for any $\mathcal{F}\in\mathsf{D}_{\textrm{qc}}(X).$ (See section 1 of "Perfect Complexes on Algebraic Stacks" by Hall and Rydh for details.)
Let $f : X\to\mathcal{Y}$ be a flat morphism from an algebraic space $X$ to an algebraic stack $\mathcal{Y}$ over some base scheme $S$ and $\Delta : X\to X\times_{\mathcal{Y}} X$ be the relative diagonal of $f.$ Suppose also that $\mathcal{F}$ is a complex of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules with quasi-coherent cohomology, and that $\mathbf{L}\Delta^*\mathbf{R}\Delta_*\mathcal{F}\in\mathsf{D}_{\textrm{qc}}(X).$
Does this guarantee that the natural comparison map
$$\mathbf{L}\Delta^*\mathbf{R}(\Delta_{\textrm{qc}})_*\mathcal{F}\to\mathbf{L}\Delta^*\mathbf{R}\Delta_*\mathcal{F}$$
is an isomorphism? If it does not guarantee this in general, are there conditions on $\mathcal{F}$ which would make this true? I would be happy to assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is a genuine quasi-coherent sheaf on $X,$ and possibly more as well.
I'm interested in the question above, and potentially generalizations of it, but I would also be interested in an answer in the case when $X$ is a scheme. I know that this will be true when $\Delta$ is qcqs, but I want to avoid restricting my attention to this situation if possible.
Edit with further thoughts: As discussed in the comments, $\Delta$ is separated, but not necessarily quasi-compact. I haven't seen much in the literature dealing with the quasi-coherent pushforward for a separated but not quasi-compact morphism, so I'm not sure to what extent this helps.
One thing which could possibly be valuable is the construction of a natural transformation $Q_{X}\mathbf{L}\Delta^*\to \mathbf{L}\Delta^* Q_{X\times_{\mathcal{Y}} X},$ where $Q_S$ denotes the derived coherator functor $\mathsf{D}(S)\to\mathsf{D}_{\textrm{qc}}(S).$ This would construct a morphism
$$\mathbf{L}\Delta^*\mathbf{R}\Delta_*\mathcal{F} = Q_{X}\mathbf{L}\Delta^*\mathbf{R}\Delta_*\mathcal{F}\to \mathbf{L}\Delta^*Q_{X\times_{\mathcal{Y}} X}\mathbf{R}\Delta_*\mathcal{F}=\mathbf{L}\Delta^*\mathbf{R}(\Delta_{\textrm{qc}})_*\mathcal{F},$$
which would hopefully provide the desired inverse. Of course, it could be too much to hope for that such a transformation exists in general.
Of course, one could find an explicit $\mathcal{G}$ completing a distinguished triangle $[\mathbf{R}(\Delta_{\textrm{qc}})_*\mathcal{F}\to\mathbf{R}\Delta_*\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}\to]$ and then analyze (the cohomology of) $\mathbf{L}\Delta^*\mathcal{G}.$ I was trying to avoid an argument as explicit as this, but it could be the most fruitful approach. Does this strategy become any more reasonable if $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{O}_X$?

Sorry by $\mathbf{L}f^\ast$ do you mean $\mathbf{L}(f_{\text{qc}})^\ast$? The left-derived pullback does not exist for a general morphism of algebraic stacks (the usual non-functoriality of the lisse-etale site).

Also, if $f$ is qcqs (in addition to being representable), then $\mathbf{R}(f_{\text{qc}})\ast$ and $\mathbf{R}f\ast$ coincide. Do you want to assume this as well? Depending on the algebraic stack you're looking at, the diagonal could be qcqs.

@DavidBenjaminLim -- thanks for the comments; I've edited the question accordingly. I don't want to use $\mathbf{L}(f_\textrm{qc})^$, since it wouldn't make sense to apply that to $\mathbf{R}f_\mathcal{F}$ in general, so now we're only dealing with a morphism between algebraic spaces (although I'd still be interested in potential generalizations if an answer can be obtained in this situation). I know that the two pushforwards coincide when the map is qcqs, but since the stack I care about is not very well behaved, I don't want to assume this outright.

That being said, I wouldn't be opposed to hearing about mild conditions which imply $\Delta$ is qcqs (or if I'm being silly and it nearly always is qcqs or something). However again, the stack I care about isn't the nicest (it's very large), so some more typical situations might not apply.

The diagonal is always separated. See this: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04YQ. Your question as it stands seems hard to understand - almost everything in Jack's paper assumes the stacks in question are concentrated. Can you say exactly what kinda stack are you dealing with?

@DavidBenjaminLim The stack I'm most interested in is Olsson's stack parameterizing fine log structures. In particular, an algebraic stack locally of finite presentation over the base scheme, whose diagonal is representable, locally separated, and of finite presentation. However, it is not quasi-separated. I want to be able to consider general log structures, so I don't want to place assumptions on the morphism $X\to\mathcal{Y}.$ I'm more happy to place restrictions on $X,$ but I'd prefer it to be as general as possible.

Hmm ok. As it stands I really don't know how to answer your question. I don't really know what to make of the assumption that $\mathbf{L}\Delta^\ast \mathbf{R} \Delta_\ast \mathcal{F} \in \mathrm{D}_{\text{qc}}(X)$. If $\Delta$ is not even qcqs then you have nothing really. No projection formula, base change theorem, compact generation by perfect complexes, etc.

@DavidBenjaminLim Yeah, I've been struggling with this as well -- thanks for your thoughts. The quasi-coherated derived pushforward is hard to work with, especially after the derived pullback. The assumption comes from the following: we can define Hochschild homology as the pullback of the pushforward of the structure sheaf (or more generally a sheaf of modules), and it turns out that this is in $\mathsf{D}_{\textrm{qc}}(X)$ although there's a priori no formal reason for this. The quasi-coherated version is however more natural in the context of DAG, and I was hopeful that the two agree.

I'm reading Theorem 3.2 here: http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_2003_4_36_5_747_0.pdf and it says that the diagonal is at least of finite presentation. But finitely presented morphisms are qcqs!

@DavidBenjaminLim I should have noticed that much sooner! However, I'm don't think that totally solves the issue, unless I'm missing something: I'm want to consider the relative diagonal of $f : X\to\mathcal{L}!\operatorname{og}_{(S,\mathcal{M}S)},$ not the diagonal of $\mathcal{L}!\operatorname{og}{(S,\mathcal{M}_S)}$ itself. After all, $\Delta_f$ is quasi-compact if and only if $f$ is quasi-separated.

@DavidBenjaminLim If I assume that $X$ in addition is itself qcqs, then I believe the argument below making use of your observation from theorem 3.2 proves the result I want.

Thanks to David Benjamin Lim's comment above, I have found an answer in the main case of interest to me, detailed below. However, I will leave this question open, since I am also interested in the answer when the diagonal of the stack in question is not qcqs, and when the algebraic space $X$ is not qcqs.
Proposition: Let $(S,\mathcal{M})$ be a fine log scheme, and let $\mathcal{L}$ be Olsson's log stack classifying fine log structures over $(S,\mathcal{M}).$ Let $f : X\to\mathcal{L}$ be a morphism from a qcqs algebraic space over $S,$ and let $\Delta : X\to X\times_{\mathcal{L}} X$ be the relative diagonal of $f.$ Then $\mathbf{R}(\Delta_{\textrm{qc}})_*$ and $\mathbf{R}\Delta_*$ coincide.
Proof: By Theorem 3.2 of "Logarithmic Geometry and Algebraic Stacks," the diagonal of $\mathcal{L}\to S$ is representable, locally separated, and of finite presentation. In particular, $\Delta_{\mathcal{L}} : \mathcal{L}\to\mathcal{L}\times_S\mathcal{L}$ is qcqs. Since $X\times_{\mathcal{L}} X\cong \mathcal{L}\times_{\mathcal{L}\times_S \mathcal{L}}(X\times_S X),$ it follows that the base change $X\times_{\mathcal{L}} X\to X\times_S X$ of $\Delta_{\mathcal{L}}$ is also qcqs.
By assumption, the diagonal $X\to X\times_S X$ is quasi-compact. Since this morphism factors as $X\to X\times_{\mathcal{L}} X\to X\times_S X,$ and the morphism $X\times_{\mathcal{L}} X\to X\times_S X$ is quasi-separated as shown above, it follows from Lemma 67.8.9 of the Stacks Project that $X\to X\times_{\mathcal{L}} X$ is quasi-compact.
Because $X\to\mathcal{L}$ is representable, $\Delta$ is separated. Then $\Delta : X\to X\times_{\mathcal{L}} X$ is qcqs, and therefore $\mathbf{R}(\Delta_{\textrm{qc}})_*$ and $\mathbf{R}\Delta_*$ agree. $\square$

+1 for your answer. You probably already know this but if $X \to Y$ is not quasi-compact then the two pushforwards don’t have to agree. For instance take $Y$ to be any affine scheme you like and $X$ to be a countable disjoint union of $Y$. Then $f_\ast\mathcal{O}X$ is not quasi-coherent and so $\mathbf{R}f\ast \mathcal{O}X$ cannot live in $\mathrm{D}{\text{qc}}(Y)$.
